# VS2008 Create custom looking form using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, forms, graphic

I have a Windows App with custom dialog forms. i was wondering if it is possible to use a custom graphic with a shadow as the actual form instead of the box shaped form. I have already been able to create the form with the graphic but the shadow does not appear correct. I have tried gif jpg bmp and png but to no success.

Comment: It might be useful to post an screen-shot of a mock-up of what is desired. Also, is WPF or WinForms being used? (It makes a big difference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some interesting stuff here: http://dotnetrix.co.uk/form.htm